# Swift 4 conversion - Type 'NSLayoutConstraint' has no member 'FormatOptions'. What would be the right call?

Tags: ios, swift4.2

I have this section of code:

```
let menuScrollView_constraint_H:Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[menuScrollView]|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
let menuScrollView_constraint_V:Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[menuScrollView(\(menuHeight))]", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
```

And I keep getting **"has no member"** compiler errors for all of the `NSData` types in this class.

This library I'm using was apparently updated to Swift 4.2.  How come these compiler errors are happening?

For example, I noticed there is a public struct called NSLayoutFormatOptions. Would I use that instead? If so, how would I use it?

Thank you for any insights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no options need to be specified, send an empty array:

```
let menuScrollView_constraint_H:Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[menuScrollView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
let menuScrollView_constraint_V:Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[menuScrollView(\(menuHeight))]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
```

If options need to be specified, choose needed from the `FormatOptions` Option set and write like I did below (I Used `.alignAllBottom` for sample):

```
let menuScrollView_constraint_H:Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[menuScrollView]|", options: .alignAllBottom, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
        let menuScrollView_constraint_V:Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[menuScrollView(\(menuHeight))]", options: .alignAllBottom, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
```

List of `FormatOptions` with descriptions can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint/formatoptions)

Comment: This helped! Thank you

Comment: Was happy to help! Would appreciate if you mark it as an answer ;)